# How to change camel idempotent table name?

Tags: apache-camel

Is there an easy way to change the idempotent control table (found as part of JdbcIdempotentRepository) from "camel_messageprocessed" to something else or does one have to subclass/edit code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change all the SQL statements using the setters: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-sql/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/processor/idempotent/jdbc/JdbcMessageIdRepository.java

However if you just want to change the table name, then it would be nicer if we had a setter for this. You are welcome to create a JIRA ticket and help implement this and provide a PR